# Allow filtering not working as expected

Tags: cassandra

I'm having issues with getting `ALLOW FILTERING` to work. In our Cassandra 1.2 database, we have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
    partition_key text,
    other_key     text,
    non_key       text,
    PRIMARY KEY (partition_key, other_key)
```

Based on [the documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selAllowFilt), this query ought to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE 
    partition_key = 'foo'
    AND other_key > 'bar'
    AND non_key = 'baz'
LIMIT 100
ALLOW FILTERING
```

However, I get this error:

> Unable to execute CQL script on 'Your Keyspace': No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator

Even this simpler query fails with the same error:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE 
    partition_key = 'foo'
    AND other_key = 'bar'
    AND non_key = 'baz'
LIMIT 100
ALLOW FILTERING
```

Yes, I'm aware that you can add secondary indexes to tables, but I thought the whole point of `ALLOW FILTERING` is to enable exceptions when you're ok with the fact that a potentially large amount of scanning is possible.

It seems like `ALLOW FILTERING` is completely broken. Why they heck doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears this feature is deceptive and what you're trying to do is not yet possible. Slated for v3.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6377